# Loop through levels beginning with bronze

Tags: php, loops

I have a table with 20 different plans.

plans.sql

```
id | planName
1  | Alpha
2  | Omega
3  | Gamma
...
```

Each plan contains 3 different levels (Bronze, Silver, Gold). I want to display all the plans on a page like this:

```
Alpha   Alpha  Alpha
Bronze  Silver Gold

Omega  Omega  Omega
Bronze Silver Gold
...
```

So far I'm pulling the plan names from the database with a while loop as follow:

```
$plansql = "select * from plans";
$resultps = $conn->query($plansql);

$resultp = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultps) > 0) {
while($plan = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultps)) {
$resultp[] = '<div class="col-lg-2">
<div class="panel price panel-red">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    <h3>'.$plan['planName'].'</h3>
                                            <h3>'.$planLevel.'</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body text-center">
                        <p class="lead panel-body-pricing" style=""><strong>'.$plan['planPrice'].'</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> 
                                                    This plan is perfect for...
                                                    </li>
                                                    </ul>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" href="#">SEE DETAILS</a>
                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>';
}
}
```

I display the result outside the while loop

```
.join("",$resultp).
```

It works great, but how do I add the different levels to each plan?

Comment: just another query and a loop inside your loop is something you wan to avoid?

Comment: @Alex: I just need to display the output outside the loop. For the rest it's okay. I was thinking with a foreach loop but I can't see how to achieve this.

Comment: Are you hoping to display the data as html? As text?

Comment: @MichaelBeeson: As html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display it as an html table, you could use this

```
echo '<table>';
foreach ($resultp as $planName) {
    echo "<tr>
          <td>$planName<br>Bronze</td>
          <td>$planName<br>Silver</td>
          <td>$planName<br>Gold</td>
          </tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Nice!  bit surprising, but yes, even this should work! :-)))

Comment: @MichaelBeeson: I can't output this in a table. I actually display them as little cards with css in the while loop. So do you suggest this to be inside the loop?

Comment: Yeah, it's what I would do. Instead of $resultp[] = $plan['planName']; I would put the output stuff there. But it's hard to help without knowing the parameters

Comment: @MichaelBeeson: I edited my question. Does it make more sense? I'm building the card inside the while loop but I need to display it somewhere else on the page. That's why I use join().

Comment: Again forgive me if I'm not getting it, but you could store the html output as a string, then echo that string later. So in my answer you would replace echo with $result .=, then when you want the data displayed, write "echo $result"